# Don't understand the seq function

Tags: r, seq

I'm reading a book on R and I don't understand the behavior of the `seq` function. Can someone please explain to me what it's doing when you give it a vector such as what is shown below on line 4?

```
> seq(1,5,1)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
> x <- c(1,5,1)
> seq(x)
[1] 1 2 3
```

Comment: All the answers to your questions are in `?seq`.

Comment: Here it gives the sequence of length of x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`seq` generates a sequence basically, so:

```
seq(from, to, increment)
```

printed out 1 to 5 incrementing by 1 each time.

Then the `c` function combines lists or vectors. So it has added the variables to x and then `seq` is performed on x which by default calls `seq_len` which outputs a sequence of 1 to `length(x)`.

Check the documenation in the links below to see the default methods.

Sequence generation: [seq](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/seq.html)
Combine/concatenate: [c](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/c.html)

Comment: Incomplete answer to the question.

Comment: No its not lol, geez people are so quick to downvote. cheers. anyway @vitalious check out the links for a much more detailed explanation.